# C# How to read and write data from Excel using Interop, without making Excel visible?

Tags: c#, excel, interop

When opening a workbook from 2 .xls files, the workbooks become visible in the background. This is undesirable in general as it does not look nice, but it also slows down the program.

Questions regarding this have been asked before, but none of the answers solved the problem. The way I am reading data from the .xls file is as follows;

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlWorkbook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path1);
xlWorksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkbook2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path2);
xlWorksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook2.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

I have tried the following ways to open the workbooks, while preventing them from becoming visible;

1.

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application() { Visible = false };
xlWorkbook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path1);
xlWorksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkbook2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path2);
xlWorksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook2.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

2.

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlApp.Visible = false;
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
xlWorkbook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path1);
xlWorksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkbook2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path2);
xlWorksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook2.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
```

3.

```
xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
xlWorkbook1 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path1);
xlWorksheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook1.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlWorkbook2 = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(path2);
xlWorksheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet) xlWorkbook2.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
xlApp.Visible = false;
xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
```

Method 3 does hide the workbooks, but they are opened first and therefore does not solve the problem. I have also tried to open the workbooks as read-only, but that does not seem to make a difference. I need to be able to write to the workbooks as well, so opening them as read-only is no option. It did not fix the problem anyway, but I'm just stating it so it will not be suggested as the solution.

Does anyone know how to achieve the desired behavior?

NOTE: I am using Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the file was in sharing mode and this made the file show up. I have turned sharing mode off and now its fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I used the NetOffice.ExcelApi for reading Excel files. I created a class for this. This should not show the Excel file or Excel itself. Don't forget to close and dispose the file, otherwise Excel will keep running in the background and that could crash your PC.

```
using NetOffice.ExcelApi;

public class ExcelFile
{
    private Application _excelApp;
    private readonly Workbook _workbook;
    private Range _range;

    private ExcelFile(string path)
    {
        _excelApp = new Application();
        _workbook = _excelApp.Workbooks.Open(path);
    }

    private void CloseFile()
    {
        _workbook.Close(0);
        _excelApp.Quit();
        _excelApp.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Willem. I am initializing `_excelApp` as `System.Windows.Application`, but it does not contain a definition for 'Workbooks'. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: You need to use NetOffice.ExcelApi, its a NuGet package, see https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetOffice.Excel/

Comment: Right, now it is recognized when I initialize as `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application`, but it does not recognize `_excelApp.Dispose()`.

Comment: Did you install the NuGet package? If so, dont use `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application` but add this to the usings: `using NetOffice.ExcelApi;`

Comment: Okay got it. Now I am trying to read data from the file, but I dont know how. Sorry I am quite new to these kind of things..

Comment: Actually, the excel file is visible this way too :(

Comment: There are multiple ways to read data from a file. Like I said, its almost the same as Excel Interop. You could just access a specific cell by first selecting the worksheet and then get the cell by using this: `var worksheet = ((Worksheet) _workbook.Sheets[0]); var cellValue = (string)worksheet.Cells[10, 2].Value;`. You could also loop to the whole used range. You can get the range by doing this: `var worksheet = ((Worksheet) _workbook.Sheets[0]); var usedRange = worksheet.UsedRange;`. Use the debugger to see what is in de objects.

Comment: Hm, thats weird. What kind of file are you using and what do you see? Excel opening the file or excel running in the background?

Comment: A .xls file, Excel opens the file.

Comment: Apparently, the file was in sharing mode and this made the file show up. I have turned sharing mode off and now its fixed. But thank you for your help :)

Comment: Good to know that as well.. No problem ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
xlApp.Visible = false;
```

try use this code